# How can I include a variable in a match regular expression in Perl, and check if the variable is NOT in the string?

Tags: regex, string, perl, variables, match

I would like to include a variable in a match regular rexpression, in Perl, and check if the variable is NOT in the string.

The link [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm#VariableAsMatchExpression) instructs how to include the variable, but I'm having difficulty testing if the variable is NOT matched.  Sure, I could just negate an if conditional like this:

```
if (!($string =~ m/$Myvar/)) {
# Do some code here
}
```

But I'm sure there must be a way to do within the regular expression match.
Any ideas?

Thank you for your help, in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`!~`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) operator.

```
if ($string !~ m/$Myvar/) {
# Do some code here
}
```

Or use [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) and avoid the regular expression engine altogether.  This will work even if `$Myvar` has characters that the regular expression engine treats specially.

```
if ( index($string, $Myvar) < 0 ) {
# Do some code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with negating the result?

A "negative match" (requiring a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) makes your regex much more complicated:

```
if ($string =~ m/^(?!.*$Myvar)/s) {
    # Do some code here
}
```